# Clevertap for IONIC push notification not working for IOS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, clevertap

I have built an app using IONIC 1 and using clevertap for analytics and push notification. I am using an official cordova plugin to consume CLEVERTAP push notifications,

[CleverTap Cordova Plugin](https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-cordova)

For android it is working fine but for IOS it is not working. Can anyone help me with this?

Here the sample initialization code,

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener('onCleverTapProfileSync', this.onCleverTapProfileSync, false);
    document.addEventListener('onCleverTapProfileDidInitialize', this.onCleverTapProfileDidInitialize, false);
    document.addEventListener('onCleverTapInAppNotificationDismissed', this.onCleverTapInAppNotificationDismissed, false);
    document.addEventListener('onDeepLink', this.onDeepLink, false);
    document.addEventListener('onPushNotification', this.onPushNotification, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
   $rootScope.CleverTap = CleverTap;
   CleverTap.notifyDeviceReady();
   CleverTap.registerPush();

},
onCleverTapProfileSync: function(e) {
    console.log(e.updates);
},
onCleverTapProfileDidInitialize: function(e) {
    console.log(e.CleverTapID);
},
onCleverTapInAppNotificationDismissed: function(e) {
    console.log(e.extras);
    console.log(e.actionExtras);
},
onDeepLink: function(e) {
    console.log(e.deeplink);
},
onPushNotification: function(e) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e.notification));
},
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log('parseElement', parentElement, id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}};app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting up push notifications for iOS you need to follow the steps given in the below link to setup your Apple certificates -

[Setting Up Push Notifications for your app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW6)

If you plan on using deep links, check the following link -

[Setting up deep links](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1)

And then from your Javascript file, use the following code to push the APNs token to CleverTap -

```
CleverTap.registerPush();
```

Let me know if this was useful to you. If you have more questions or concerns you can always reach out to CleverTap support team at support@clevertap.com

Comment: I have added the sample code of push notification initialization. Let me know.

Comment: Did you setup the APNs certificates as well?

Comment: Yes, I did. Without that, you can not register to push notification on Clevertap.

Comment: @NitinD Did you save the APNs certificates on CleverTap dashboard?

Comment: I would suggest you write to us at support@clevertap.com and mentioning your account ID so that we can check what exactly is happening on the dashboard level and how we can resolve this quickly for you. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: I already did write to you. I got the resonse saying add verbose debugging.

Comment: Thanks for writing in, I will personally make sure your issue gets resolved as soon as possible